# Why the for loop is not working for particular values?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{   
    FILE *wg = NULL;  
    wg = fopen("wangdata.txt","w");
    if(wg == NULL)
    {
         printf("Error in opening file wg!\n");
    }

    int vertices = 100, edges = 400, i; // 20,50:(100,50)
    int strings = 160;
    int v1, v2,j;
    double t=0.0;
    double dt=0.1;
    double b[strings];
    double x[vertices], x1[vertices];
    double x2[vertices];
    unifRand(x,x1,x2);

    struct Edge * adjacencyList[vertices + 1];
    // Size is made (vertices + 1) to use the
    // array as 1-indexed, for simplicity

    // initialize array:
    for (i = 0; i <= vertices; ++i) {
        adjacencyList[i] = NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= edges; ++i) {
        //scanf(%d%d", &v1, &v2);
        v1 = rand()%100;
        v2 = rand()%100; 

        // Adding edge v1 --> v2
        // Add edge from v1 --> v2
        if(v1 != v2)
        adjacencyList[v1] = addEdge(adjacencyList[v1], v2);

        // Adding edge v2 --> v1
        // Remove this if you want a Directed Graph
        adjacencyList[v2] = addEdge(adjacencyList[v2], v1);
    }

    // Printing Adjacency List
    printf("\nAdjacency List -\n\n");
    for(j=0; j<strings; j++){

       for (i = 0; i <= vertices; ++i) {
            printf("adjacencyList[%d] -> ", i);
            struct Edge * traverse = adjacencyList[i];
            while (traverse != NULL)
            {
              b[j] = j/vertices;
              fprintf(wg,"%d %d \t\t%0.3lf\t\t\t%0.1lf\t%0.6lf\t\n", i, traverse->vertex, (-log(1-x[i])*(traverse->vertex)),b[j],x[i]);
              printf("%d -> ", traverse->vertex);
              traverse = traverse->next;
            }
            printf("NULL\n");
       }
     }

   return 0;
   fclose(wg);
   wg = NULL;
}
```

The above for loop in the main function, only prints `0` and `1` for `b[j]`, in the output file. While printing `j` it prints all the values of `j`, but the loop does not work for `b[j]`. I dont know where it goes wrong?. I am defining `b[j]` as the number of strings normalized by the total vertices (network size in the language of graph theory).

Comment: Where is vertices declared ? Please add more of your code.

Comment: Are you *sure* about the loop condition `i <= vertices`?

Comment: Did you mean `b[j] = j/i;` ?

Comment: Is `vertices` or `j`  integers? maybe if you cast it to double?

Comment: You need to say what the values involved are and what results you expected. We can't help if we don't know what this is supposed to do.

Comment: I have now edited and given the complete code from the main()

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing an `int` by an `int`. It will result an `int` value. Since `j` will be always below `vertices`, you will get `0`

Try

```
b[j] = (double)j/(double)vertices;
```

Comment: Failed to notice the trivial issue. It works now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

`j` goes from 0 to 159 and is divided by 100. Since integer division rounds towards zero, this gives 0 or 1.

If you want a non-rounded `double` result, cast one or both of the numbers to `double` before division:

```
b[j] = j / (double) vertices;
```